# How to disable automatically browser opening on Wi-Fi hotspot connection for Win10?

Tags: browser, automation, windows-10, wifi

When I connect my laptop to a free/public **Wi-Fi hotspot** (FreeWifi, Orange...), **Windows 10** opens automatically my default Web browser and goes if possible to the ISP captive portal.
So each time I connect to the Wi-Fi SSID my browser is opened.

Quite good for a normal usage, but not for web browser testing!

How can I disable the action that opens the browser each time I connect to the Wi-Fi hotspot ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One solution I found is to modify directly a Windows regitry :

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet\EnableActiveProbing

And to do it from a Batch script, I purpose this :

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet" /v EnableActiveProbing /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

- REG ADD : add/modify a registry;
- Then specify the repository of the registry;
- /v EnableActiveProbing : indicates the **v**alue to modify;
- /t REG_DWORD : indicates **t**ype of value;
- /d 0 : gives the **d**ata to add;
- /f : to **f**orce changes.

*(More help with REG ADD /h)*

It works fine on Windows 10 with admin rights.
Hope it will help some people.

Comment: This works well. Mark your own answer as accepted! 

Comment: This registry entry also appears in Win 8, so hopefully it works there as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest the following short solution for the noobie.

**Disable:**
Save following text to a disable.reg file, and then double-click on it. That will modify the registry accordingly:

`Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`
`; Use this if delaying startup of NlaSvc does not work`

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet]
"EnableActiveProbing"=dword:00000000`

**Enable:**
Save following text to a enable.reg file, and then double-click on it. That will modify the registry accordingly:

`Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`
`; Use this if delaying startup of NlaSvc does not work`

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet]`
`"EnableActiveProbing"=dword:00000001`

Answer (score 1):

By changing **EnableActiveProbing** to **0** actually leading wifi adapter to show not connected but by changing
**ActiveWebProbeHost** **[www.msftncsi.com](http://www.msftncsi.com)**
To
**[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)**
fixed auto opening browser when we enable wifi and not showing any error.